# Conservation of momenta in the solar system

Tags: angular-momentum, momentum, conservation-laws, computational-physics, solar-system

I am writing a python program to simulate the universe and I had a question regarding conservation laws. As rightly stated in these [answers](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/174691/conservation-of-angular-momentum-in-a-planetary-system/174703),  "Both are conserved if you consider the whole system ... (but) subsystems may violate conservation laws." From this, I took that as a whole the solar system will conserve both angular and linear momentum, but for instance, the Sun-Earth interaction will not, and conserve only angular momentum. In my simulation, however, I am not sure why my linear momentum for the whole system is fluctuating so much. All the other values are conserved to a high degree such as $KE + PE =$ constant and angular momentum, however, I am failing to wrap my head around the linear momentum. [image: 2] [image: 3]

The linear momentum varies by up to $75%$ however the angular momentum varies by far less than $1%$. The axis is just a bit deceiving for the angular momentum so it looks more. If I am correct the linear momentum should be constant so why is it fluctuating so much?

Update: Extra Figures

[image]
[image]

The top figure shows the individual components of linear momentum over time. The second figure showing the $x$ component of the linear momentum over time.

Comment: Why does the angular momentum decrease by half if it's conserved?

Comment: It doesn't decrease by half the scale is just very confusing, I do need to change it. The angular momentum decreases from ≈ 10*1e36 **+3.8e43** to 5*1e36 **+3.8e43**.  So actually only decreases by **1.3e-5%**

Comment: What is the meaning of the values in bold?

Comment: They are just values, in bold to indicate why the angular momentum is decreasing by 50%. The reason being the scale on the graph is in the order of e36 but the true value is e46 added to the value on the graph. Indicating that the e36 is insignificant in comparison to e43. Hope that clears some things up

Comment: The last figure seems to show the black (sun) linear momentum cancelling the green and  purple ones approximately, i.e from those three they'll add to zero approximately...

Comment: They don't add to zero they add to what is shown in the third Figure which is $\approx$ 1e17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started to write a comment. However, I eventually decided that it could be more useful as a full answer, since it covers a point that is often overlooked, even in the literature.

The general problem is *how can we decide how well the numerical integration of the equation of motion satisfies some exact conservation law?*

The general answer is the following. As soon as a conserved quantity $A$ is the sum of different terms ($A=\sum_i A_i $), the time variation of $A$ should be compared with each $A_i$ and significantly smaller. In the case of a conserved quantity, the non-exact numerical conservation is only due to a combination of the error due to the integration algorithm, and round-off error. The former is usually dominant and can be easily identified from the decrease of the relative size of the variation of $A$ with respect to variations of $A_i$ with decreasing the time step. In some cases, when using [symplectic algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_integrator), the algorithm does not contribute to the error and only the time-step-independent round-off error remains.

For example, in order to judge the conservation of one of the cartesian components of the total linear momentum of the bodies in the solar system, one has to compare it to the corresponding component of the linear momentum of one of the planets.  Done the comparison in this way, the variations in the corresponding plot should look very small. Actually, the best way to look at the results is to put *on the same plot* say $p_{tot,x}$ and, for example, $p_{Mercury,x}$. From the figure in the original question, I would suspect an excellent conservation of linear momentum.

Similarly for other quantities; for instance, the total angular momentum could be compared with $m_ix_i v_{y,i}$, or the total energy with $\frac12 m_i v^2_{x,i}$.

Notice that there are papers in the literature where the conservation of energy is assessed in terms of the percentage variation of the total energy with respect to its initial value. Such a procedure is clearly meaningless, as soon as one realizes that energies are always defined within an arbitrary constant. Therefore the absolute value of the initial (or average energy) is not a safe quantity to be used in a comparison. *Variations* must be compared with other *variations*.

Comment: Ok, I think I am understanding what you are saying. Is it that one should compare the components individually as apposed to an averaging out of the value? If so do my new figures shed any additional light as to what's going on in my system?

Comment: @HarrySpratt Yes, they completely clarify the situation. Individual components of the total momentum vary almost 15 orders of magnitude less than each planet x component. This implies that, assuming 64-bit representation for your floating-point numbers, your integration algorithm conserves the momentum within machine precision.  Additional proof of that comes from the irregular variation: just round-off error. Such behavior is expected if you are using a symplectic algorithm. Within the precision you are using, you cannot have better conservation of momentum.

Comment: I have slightly modified the third paragraph to clarify the role of algorithmic and round-off error.

Answer (score 1):

You should also include the linear momentum of the Sun.

The planets, especially Jupiter, cause the Sun to move slightly and it orbits around the 'barycenter' the true center of mass of the solar system.

After question edit:

If the momentum of the Sun is already included...

The variation is approximately the momentum of Jupiter, so it's a big variation.  Here are a some suggestions.

1. To check the numbers for Jupiter
2. Check the direction of the momentum / time relation is ok
3. Check that the momentum used is relative to the barycenter.

Hope you can find the problem...

Comment: Sorry that was my mistake, I mislabelled it planets instead of objects but it does include the values for the Sun in the graph. I have subsequently changed the graph.

Comment: OK, will edit the post if there is a better idea to present...

Comment: @Harry Spratt How are you getting the directions for each planet at a specific time?

Comment: I am using ```sci.integrate.solve_ivp``` in which I input my initial conditions and my function for gravity and it outputs $\dot{x}$ and $\ddot{x}$

Comment: OK, does it give a direction for x dot?  The momentum will be conserved in a specific direction, so for example you might need  x dot$\times \cos\theta$ where $\theta$ is the angle to a specified direction...

Comment: oh ok, that's something I failed to do nor think about. $\dot{x}$ does not have a specified direction at the moment. Its just the magnitude

Comment: @Harry Spratt, ok, it would be interesting to see  a post, if it improves things, all the best

Comment: @Harry Spratt Did you find the problem?  Did considering linear momentum in a specific direction help?  Your extra figure (second from the bottom) has lower ($1\times 10^{17}$) fluctuation, what is that figure about?

Comment: The figure second from the bottom shows the individual components of the momentum, in the x,y and z-direction. The z is the one that is the smallest.

Answer (score 1):

All numerical computing involves some amount of rounding error, and some amount of compromise between insulating against rounding error and algorithm speed. So the first question you have to ask should be “is this loss of precision a lot?”

It certainly *looks* like a lot, with your $10^{31}$ and $10^{36}$ in your plot axis labels. But you point out in a comment (and hiding in your axis labels in a slightly confusing way) that the *total* angular momentum in your solar system is of order $10^{43}$. (You don’t say, but I guess you are probably working in SI units, and those are joule-seconds.) So what you actually have is a change in the total angular momentum of your solar system at the part-per-million level. If I’m correctly reading Saturn’s orbit off of the plot with planetary motions, this is a part-per-million change over a hundred years of integration.

Part-per-million rounding errors are a place where your algorithm might be able to improve, but nothing to sneeze at.

I don’t quite understand how your first figure is related to your third figure (in v4 of your question). But comparing your third and fourth figures: if you have linear momentum components oscillating with amplitude $10^{31}$ (whether that’s $\rm kg\,m/s$ or some other unit) and the sums of those components are steady at the level of $10^{17}$ in the same units, you’re operating pretty close to the limit for double-precision computer arithmetic.  Nothing to complain about there.

It’s always helpful, when modeling, to choose a “natural unit” for your problem so that you have some idea whether an effect is big or not. Back in the days of single-precision floating-point you would have stumbled onto this requirement already: your angular momentum $10^{43}$ [can’t even be represented in single precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format), and your total linear momentum $10^{31}$ would be subject to overflow if you computed its magnitude the “obvious” way

```
p = sqrt(p_x**2 + p_y**2) # generates 10^{62}-ish intermediate value
```

versus the more subtle

```
a, b = sorted(p_x, p_y) # guarantee a < b
p = b * sqrt( 1 + (a/b)**2 )
```

I vaguely recall the second approach has better accuracy even when overflow is not an issue, but I don’t remember a detailed argument for why; it probably depends on the details of rounding errors in `sqrt`.

I like to use [astronomical natural units](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/112541/44126) for solar-system models. Instead of meters, kilograms, and seconds, use astronomical units (AU), solar masses, and years. Figuring out useful reference values for planetary linear and angular momenta in those units, or even in SI units, is a chore which will help you understand the numerical side of your problem a little better.

Comment: Using *natural units* has an old tradition in this field. However, in the present days, there is no additional cost (and in python is the default) using double precision. Moreover, using natural units makes it more difficult to guess a reasonable time step of integration to start with: in SI units I know for sure that one day, $\Delta t=86400 s$, is a reasonable time step for the Earth-Sun system. Less obvious in natural units.

Comment: @GiorgioP I agree that it's nice to have the era of single-precision computing in the past. But I think that it's still helpful to think about time steps compared the the natural timescales of the system. I vaguely remember writing some Runge-Kutta integrator with adaptive time steps which had the best performance at about sixteen time steps per orbit; by that metric, your choice of 365 steps per Earth orbit might be too conservative.

Comment: The figure of one day per step was for a second-order symplectic integrator (Størmed-Verlet). Of course, numbers change with other integrators. For a final assessment, it would be important to compare the number of evaluations of force per time step (one for Størmed-Verlet, more than one with Runge-Kutta). However, this is marginal to the unit's issue. Once overflow problems are avoided, there is no compelling reason for using scaled units in the calculations. Rescaling adds one layer of multiplication/division between numerical results and our understanding. It is like using ...

Comment: ... a new system of units: doable, but not very comfortable.